# checkbox is not working in expandable list in php

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have the following code

```
<ul id="expList">
<li>TITLE
        <ul>
            <li>          
    </li>           
         </ul>
 </li>
     <li>INNOCULUM
         <ul>
             <li>
                 <form><table border=1 frame=border name='mytable' id='mytable'>
                        <tr><th >Select</td><th >Field</td><td>Value to be updated</td>/tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type='checkbox' name='check1'></td> 
                            <th>INNOCULUM</td>
                            <td><input type='text' name='innoculum'/></td></tr>
                        <tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='check2'></td> 
                            <th>ORGANISM</td>
                            <td><input type='text' name='organism'/></td></tr>
    </li>           
        </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

This is a sample code where i included checkbox in expandable list created using jquery. Unfortunately it is not working for me. Checkbox is not getting enabled. Please help me out

Comment: Could you include the jQuery code?

Comment: You are including the checkbox with jQuery, but its not working so you post the HTML? Please post the jQuery as well

Comment: i have no jquery code in my program i just included jquery.js for getting expendable list

Comment: how did you create the expandable list? which plugin did you use? How is the checkbox not working? can you see it? can you click it? should something happen when you click it? etc etc. more details please

Comment: i able to see the checkbox but i am unable to click the checkbox

Comment: I got the code for expandable list from [http://jasalguero.com/demos/expandableList/]

Answer (score 0):

If this is a copy and paste of your code, I found a typo:

```
<tr><th >Select</td><th >Field</td><td>Value to be updated</td>/tr>
```

Your closing `</tr>` is missing the **<**. That might be causing your problem.

Comment: Probably not, but in the same vein, the asker is not closing the table tag either

Comment: @DarkoZ ~ Depending on the browser, you can get weird behaviour if you miss things like this. It might be preventing the jQuery script from running properly.

Comment: I agree, hence the "probably". It needs to be fixed and it may be causing the problem but something tells me that its the code, where something == "if the asker is so sloppy with their HTML, they're probably just as sloppy with the jQuery". To clarify I did not downvote you :)

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox not checking is probably a result of invalid markup (as [Darko Z mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685211/checkbox-is-not-working-in-expandable-list-in-php#comment17121745_12685254), you didn't close you table, and as [Tyanna mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12685254/758177), you have an incomplete closing `</tr>` tag). Browsers sometimes do all sorts of crazy things when given invalid markup (especially with broken tags). Also, you close your `<th>` tags with `</td>`, which is wrong.

Fixing the invalid code will probably solve your checkbox issue.

**Here is your code working**: http://jsfiddle.net/jshado1/HdzqH/. All I did was fix the markup (there were actually several other markup issues as well).

Comment: no that is not the problem i erased all the code and only inserted checkbox in <li> still i am not getting it. I inserted a checkbox outside the <ul> then it is working

Comment: If all you're using is the code you provided, then markup is the culprit. See the fiddle I posted.